# Arduino r4 WiFi crash when connecting to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino-uno, arduino-esp32, arduino-uno-wifi

I was trying to make my Arduino to read the temperature of my room and send it to real time database, so I could access it easily, but when connecting it crash saying "Bus fault is caused by precise data access violation". I tried to use a library for HTTPS, thinking it was the problem but nothing.

One thing that I noted is that if I connect to "firebaseapp.com" not crash, but when trying to connect to "arduino-r4-ambient-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app" it does.
When connecting to "europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app" `ERROR.mConnectBasicClient: Failed to connect to server using basic client.`

This is the code that I used:
*I removed some lines that I do not use, like "sendToFirebase" function and some #define constant containg firebase keys*

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "WiFiS3.h"
#include <ESP_SSLClient.h>


ESP_SSLClient ssl_client;
WiFiClient basic_client;

#define SSID "TIM-88519218"
#define PASSWORD "*************"

const char* firebaseHost = "arduino-r4-ambient-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app";  // /v1/projects/arduino-r4-ambient/databases/(default)/documents/ambient

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;


void connectFB() {
  //WiFiClient client;
  Serial.println("mi sto per connettere");
  bool connectionResult = ssl_client.connect(firebaseHost, 443);

  delay(1000);


  Serial.print("Connection result: ");
  Serial.println(connectionResult ? "Success" : "Failed");

  if (connectionResult) {
    Serial.println("aaaoooooo");
    delay(500);
    ssl_client.stop();
  }
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;  // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();

  if (fv < WIFI_FIRMWARE_LATEST_VERSION) {

    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  status = WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);
  delay(10000);

  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("Signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");

  ssl_client.setInsecure();
  ssl_client.setBufferSizes(1024 /* rx */, 1024 /* tx */);
  ssl_client.setDebugLevel(1);
  ssl_client.setClient(&basic_client);


  connectFB();
  //sendToFirebase(30, 67);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

and this is the result in the Serial monitor

```
17:36:44.163 ->   addr: 20007e5c    data: 00000000
17:36:44.291 ->   addr: 20007e60    data: 00000000
17:36:44.291 ->   addr: 20007e64    data: 00017c00
17:36:44.291 ->   addr: 20007e68    data: 200002a0
17:36:44.455 ->   addr: 20007e6c    data: 000001bb
17:36:44.455 ->   addr: 20007e70    data: 0001f51a
17:36:44.455 ->   addr: 20007e74    data: 00015281
17:36:44.587 ->   addr: 20007e78    data: 0000a500
17:36:44.587 ->   addr: 20007e7c    data: 00017cdd
17:36:44.587 ->   addr: 20007e80    data: 20000278
17:36:44.587 ->   addr: 20007e84    data: 000153cf
17:36:44.719 ->   addr: 20007e88    data: ffffffc6
17:36:44.719 ->   addr: 20007e8c    data: 00004040
17:36:44.719 ->   addr: 20007e90    data: ffffffc6
17:36:44.850 ->   addr: 20007e94    data: 00004040
17:36:44.850 ->   addr: 20007e98    data: 0000a500
17:36:44.850 ->   addr: 20007e9c    data: 00004129
17:36:44.982 ->   addr: 20007ea0    data: ffffffc6
17:36:44.982 ->   addr: 20007ea4    data: 00004287
17:36:44.982 ->   addr: 20007ea8    data: 20000fcc
17:36:44.982 ->   addr: 20007eac    data: 200016d0
17:36:45.145 ->   addr: 20007eb0    data: 00000005
17:36:45.145 ->   addr: 20007eb4    data: 00000005
17:36:45.145 ->   addr: 20007eb8    data: 0002513c
17:36:45.278 ->   addr: 20007ebc    data: 00000000
17:36:45.278 ->   addr: 20007ec0    data: 00000000
17:36:45.278 ->   addr: 20007ec4    data: 00000000
17:36:45.411 ->   addr: 20007ec8    data: 4bb2a8c0
17:36:45.411 ->   addr: 20007ecc    data: 00000000
17:36:45.411 ->   addr: 20007ed0    data: 00000000
17:36:45.411 ->   addr: 20007ed4    data: 00017fb5
17:36:45.542 ->   addr: 20007ed8    data: 000251f9
17:36:45.542 ->   addr: 20007edc    data: 40046f00
17:36:45.542 ->   addr: 20007ee0    data: 00000000
17:36:45.673 ->   addr: 20007ee4    data: 00017ff7
17:36:45.673 ->   addr: 20007ee8    data: 000251f9
17:36:45.673 ->   addr: 20007eec    data: 000154ab
17:36:45.804 ->   addr: 20007ef0    data: 000251f9
17:36:45.804 ->   addr: 20007ef4    data: 000159f3
17:36:45.804 ->   addr: 20007ef8    data: 000159e9
17:36:45.804 ->   addr: 20007efc    data: 00002599
17:36:45.967 -> ====================================
17:36:45.967 -> =================== Registers information ====================
17:36:46.097 ->   R0 : 65726966  R1 : 0001fe8c  R2 : 00000000  R3 : 20000402
17:36:46.097 ->   R12: 20007cf3  LR : 000049e3  PC : 00017ae6  PSR: 410f0000
17:36:46.229 -> ==============================================================
17:36:46.229 -> Bus fault is caused by precise data access violation
17:36:46.360 -> The bus fault occurred address is 65726966
17:36:46.360 -> Show more call stack info by run: addr2line -e "/private/var/folders/kd/fclmfxnx21j2lfds68750yvc0000gn/T/arduino/sketches/53F834E1D0402592C13E101BE50B98A0/upload-dh11-to-firebase.ino".elf -a -f 00017ae6 000049e2 0000541e 00005894 00014bfa 0001c758 00015250 00015280 00017cdc 000153ce 00004128 00004286 00017fb4 00017ff6 000154aa 000159f2
```

If I run addr2line command it says that the line is
`bool connectionResult = ssl_client.connect(firebaseHost, 443);`

Does someone had the same problem? I try to search on google and asked to chatGPT but I found nothing.